# QString functions giving incorrect results on CentOS

Tags: c++, string, qt

I am using C++ Qt Library and following code is working perfectly on Windows but not working on CentOS :

```
if(line.startsWith("[", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
{
    int index = line.indexOf(']', 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    QString subLine = line.mid(index+1);
    subLine = subLine.trimmed();
    tokenList = subLine.split("\t");
}
else
{
    tokenList = line.split("\t");
}
```

I have a line [ x.x.x.x ] something `../dir/file.extension` and I want to ignore the [x.x.x.x] part while breaking line into tokens. I am using VC9 on windows to debug and its working fine.

Edit: i have removed mid() and used right() still same problem persists, working on windows but not on CentOS.

Edit: after debugging on linux using QMessageBox i have concluded that control is never going inside if block, i tried using if(line.data()[0] == '[') but same results.

Comment: Can you debug it on the mentioned OS ?

Comment: Are you reading from a file that was created on Windows?  You may have a line ending issue.

Comment: @p.i.g. i can debug it on windows but not on CentOS, i don't have a debugging env there.

Comment: _How_ is it not working? Give an example of an input string and show the two different outputs.  Also CentOS is open-source so just create a VM with it - if your customers are using a particular OS you should be testing on it.

Comment: Give the example of an input string and a wrong output string. What means "not working" in this context?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yeah that might be the case.

Comment: @vahancho
 output on  CentOS:   [x.x.x.x] key ../dir/file.extension
expected output:  key ../dir/file.extension

Comment: @cmannett85 i have developed on windows and am testing my code on a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified.

```
line.remove(QRegExp("\\[\\s+\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s+\\]"));
tokenList = line.split("\t");
```

Comment: thanks but the contents of line are dynamic i don't know the exact substring [x.x.x.x] that's why i was finding the index of ] to read string after it.

Comment: Then, you can use regular expression. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Its returning 

"[ 192.168.2.149 ] DEM-FILENAME[0] ../terrain/los_angeles-w.dem"

but i want "DEM-FILENAME[0] ../terrain/los_angeles-w.dem"

Comment: After your edit am getting " ../terrain/los_angeles-w.dem"

Comment: You need to work out the right regular expression. I'm not quite familiar with that stuff. It seem that your x.x.x.x is an ip address, and i have updated the answer again accordingly.